# Run PHP application in Apache server using PHP-FPM

Tags: php, docker, apache2, fpm

We have a php application which was running fine using
 Docker Image :

> php:7.2-apache-stretch

We now have to make use of the below image for better performance and make the application work as it was before .

> php:7.2.17-fpm-stretch

As this image does not have apache in it . I updated the Dockerfile starting from the installation of apache2 and related packages based on various forums .

There is many other steps . I have just added the instructions which I have updated in the Dockerfile.

```
 FROM php:7.2.17-fpm-stretch

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2 wget

RUN cd /tmp && wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/liba/libapache-mod-fastcgi/libapache2-mod-fastcgi_2.4.7~0910052141-1.2_amd64.deb && dpkg -i libapache2-mod-fastcgi_2.4.7~0910052141-1.2_amd64.deb;apt-get install -f

RUN a2enmod actions proxy_fcgi fastcgi
COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY info.php /var/www/html/info.php
COPY run.sh /app/run.sh
# EXPOSE 9000
RUN chmod 755 /app/run.sh
CMD "/app/run.sh"
```

The info.php contains `<?php phpinfo( ); ?>` . In the run.sh script , we start the php-fpm service and apache2 as below

> php-fpm -D
>
> /usr/sbin/apachectl -D FOREGROUND

previously  I was trying to access the app from the port which was mapped to 9000 ( fpm ) . When I accessed the correct port where apache was running , I was able to view info.php .

The Content in the vhost.conf file.

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
  SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://localhost:9000"
</FilesMatch>
```

---

Answer (score 3):

I got it working making a few modifications.

I used this slightly modified dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2.17-fpm-stretch

RUN apt-get update; apt-get install -y apache2 wget

RUN cd /tmp && wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/liba/libapache-mod-fastcgi/libapache2-mod-fastcgi_2.4.7~0910052141-1.2_amd64.deb && dpkg -i libapache2-mod-fastcgi_2.4.7~0910052141-1.2_amd64.deb;apt-get install -f


RUN a2enmod actions proxy_fcgi fastcgi

COPY run.sh /app/run.sh
RUN chmod 755 /app/run.sh
CMD "/app/run.sh"
```

I also added the following snippet (the same modification you did) to /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf:

```
<FilesMatch \.php$>
  SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://localhost:9000"
</FilesMatch>
```

Here is the output I get:

```
[09-Apr-2019 21:23:06] NOTICE: fpm is running, pid 9
[09-Apr-2019 21:23:06] NOTICE: ready to handle connections
AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully qualified domain name, using 172.17.0.2. Set the 'ServerName' directive globally to suppress this message
```

Also, did you try building the dockerfile without the cache? Sometimes, caching can cause issues with package installation (see [here](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#run) for more details). To do a clean build of an image, just use:

```
docker build --no-cache
```

Comment: Hello , thanks a lot for the response .  I missed to include . I am doing a chmod to the script and I am able to successfully start both process . But I am not sure how this whole things connects . Is my implementation in vhost.conf is correct . If we have a php app like WordPress and I have to host it in Apache server using php-fpm what are the steps to be done .

Comment: I added the following snippet to  /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf and it worked for me:
`<FilesMatch \.php$> SetHandler "proxy:fcgi://localhost:9000" </FilesMatch>`

Comment: I have updated my Dockerfile . When I try to access the info.php . I am unable to do it . While localhost is able to access index.html . :( .

Comment: Its working for a sample.php file . I have a wordpress application which was running in php: . In that Dockerfile the following mods were enabled .

Answer (score 2):

I got your new configuration working using this dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.2.17-fpm-stretch

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y apache2 wget

RUN cd /tmp && wget http://mirrors.kernel.org/ubuntu/pool/multiverse/liba/libapache-mod-fastcgi/libapache2-mod-fastcgi_2.4.7~0910052141-1.2_amd64.deb && dpkg -i libapache2-mod-fastcgi_2.4.7~0910052141-1.2_amd64.deb;apt-get install -f

RUN a2enmod actions proxy_fcgi fastcgi
COPY 000-default.conf /etc/apache2/sites-available/000-default.conf
COPY info.php /var/www/html/info.php
COPY run.sh /app/run.sh
RUN chmod 755 /app/run.sh
EXPOSE 80
CMD "/app/run.sh"
```

The command I ran was:

```
docker run -P -d --rm <php-image>
```

The exposed ports are:

> 0.0.0.0:32773->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32772->9000/tcp

I was able to access info.php using http://localhost:32773/info.php

Comment: Thanks for the response . 

Now my wordpress app is working . But I face issue with Rewrite which I have mentioned in .htaccess file .

[Wed Apr 10 15:24:03.632495 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 15:tid 139956055955200] [client 172.17.0.18:55636] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n', referer: http://local.test.com
[Wed Apr 10 15:26:53.354451 2019] [proxy_fcgi:error] [pid 16:tid 139956039169792] [client 172.17.0.18:56056] AH01071: Got error 'Primary script unknown\n', referer: http://local.test.com

Comment: What .htaccess file?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to access the php page . Everything was working fine . But I was looking in the wrong direction . When I run the container .

```
docker run -P -d --rm php:test-fpm
```

The output was

```
82071c9ff023        php:test-fpm                    "docker-php-entrypoi…"   2 seconds ago       Up 1 second         0.0.0.0:32778->80/tcp, 0.0.0.0:32777->9000/tcp   practical_mclean
```

I was accessing localhost:32777/info.php . But I should I accessed the 32778 where apache is exposed and localhost: 32778/info.php worked !!! .